# SoundRecorder.exe Executed from Ruby on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows

I am trying to run c:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe on a Windows 7 Device from Ruby.  When I run that application, I get the following error: "No such file or Directory".

I can successfully run CALC.exe without any trouble.

I verified that my computer has the following file:

```
 Directory of c:\windows\system32

07/13/2009  08:39 PM           142,336 SoundRecorder.exe
               1 File(s)        142,336 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  156,940,525,568 bytes free
```

I'm using:

```
@run_command = 'c:\windows\system32\SoundRecorder.exe'
stdin, stdout,stderr =Open3.popen3(@run_command) do |stdin,stdout,stderr,wait_thr|
                        process_pid = wait_thr[:pid]
                        p "Process Started for Execute Command: #{process_pid}"
                        exit_status = wait_thr.value    
            end
```

Here are the things I tried:

1. Ran using Calc.exe (for `@run_command`), and it worked.
2. Tried to execute this with Root privileges which failed.
3. Tried to pass in more environment variables which failed.
4. Tried to execute this via IRB and that failed.
5. Tried to execute this via ``` (back ticks) which failed.

** Additional Debugging Results ***

```
irb(main):006:0> Dir.exist? 'c:/windows/system32'
=> true

irb(main):011:0> File.exist? 'c:/windows/system32/calc.exe'
=> true

irb(main):012:0> File.exist? 'c:/windows/system32/SoundRecorder.exe'
=> false

HOWEVER before anyone says, "XXX, the file doesn't exist look here"


C:\>dir c:\windows\system32\SoundRecorder.exe
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is F099-27F4

 Directory of c:\windows\system32

07/13/2009  08:39 PM           142,336 SoundRecorder.exe
               1 File(s)        142,336 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  156,942,340,096 bytes free
```

Comment: It isn't necessary or desired you use "Executive Overview" or  like "Dear team,". SO is a reference book, not a discussion forum. Keep it concise. Incorporate the "overview" information into your question or write that concisely throughout the question.

Comment: Show us your *exact* assignment for `@run_command`.

Comment: Done:  I added the section where I run the command. I welcome you to run this in irb. It won't work! I think its a wierd Windows thing.

Comment: One thing to note: It's not necessary, or even preferred, to use back-slashes with Windows paths. Use forward-slashes instead and let Ruby convert them as necessary. Read the first section of [the IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach).

Comment: Done. Unfortunately that didn't fix anything :(. Still same problem.

Comment: Break the problem down to isolate the error: In IRB define `@run_command` then run `Dir.exist?(File.dirname(@run_command))` followed by `File.exist?(@run_command)` and look at the returned values.

Comment: File.exist? returns false. However, I can see it in my directory, when I do a DIR. I think this is some sort of Windows7 magic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102296/discussion-between-user3443386-and-the-tin-man).

Comment: It might be file permissions.  What are the permissions on `calc.exe` vs `SoundRecorder.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

This is 100 % a Windows issue.

Copy the file anywhere else, and run that.

It works. I don't know why.